# Replacing textarea with ContentEditable attribute - Javascript runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm working on a script to listen to the attribute `contenteditable` and simulate a changed handler. And the code runs multuple times. I'm not sure why that happens. Edit2: Updated the code that fixed the problem.
The code looks like this:

```
    Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);

    function init() {
        makeEditable('myeditablediv');
    }

    function makeEditable(id) {
        Event.observe(id, 'click', function(){test($p(id))}, false);
    }

    function test(obj) {
        var pre = obj.innerHTML;

        $(obj).one("focusout", function(){
            newcontent = obj.innerHTML
            alert(pre + ' ' + newcontent);
            if (newcontent !== pre) {alert('content is not the same')};         
        });
    }
```

This is originally a prototype script, that's why the `$p` because I had to change it's selector since I use jQuery as well.

In `test()` I output the previous value, then the new value. Then I try to compare these two. The next time I click the element `myeditablediv`, the previous variables are displayed, THEN the new ones. Third time I click, the first two, THEN the new third. Etc etc. I bet some of you have your facepalm ready right now, but I'm not good enough to spot this. Is it because of `Event.observe`? Edit: Edited the if statement.

Comment: jQuery and prototype are kind of concurrent, they are used to do the same thing: manipulating the DOM easily, managing events....etc. May be you should start to use only one of them, it will reduce the risk of mistake. Moreover, regading the documentation of Event.observe: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/observe/ there seems to be only 3 parameters.

Comment: How many times are you running makeEditable?

Comment: makeEditable is executed only one time, but in your test function your are adding a listener (.focusout(handler)). At each click, the test function is called, then you will add a new listener on the focus out event. At the third click, there is 3 handlers responding to the focus out.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense! How can I make sure it fires only once? Move the (.focusout(handler))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach the `.focusout` handler and have it run only once instead of adding more and more handlers each time.

So:

```
$(obj).one("focusout", function(){
    //....
});
```

Comment: That was brilliant! :) Wow, now I have a way of actually using divs instead of textareas :)